# Firebase PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

Tags: flutter, firebase, channel, platform, unhandled-exception

Suddenly this error appears in the debug console. I do not know what I did wrong.

Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)

```
E/flutter ( 6441): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel., null, null)
E/flutter ( 6441): #0      PathProviderApi.getApplicationDocumentsPath (package:path_provider_android/messages.g.dart:97:7)
E/flutter ( 6441): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6441): #1      getApplicationDocumentsDirectory (package:path_provider/path_provider.dart:115:24)
E/flutter ( 6441): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 6441): #2      _FileContainerState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:whatsapp_redesign/…/chat/file_container.dart:56
E/flutter ( 6441): <asynchronous suspension>
```

I tried to update my dependencies but they are all up to date still i m facing this error. Did someone have the same problem and solved it?